# Problems to inject a controller in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I try to define a controller for a dialog, as seen in the Angular Material examples (https://plnkr.co/edit/DlhNXU)

```
var TestApp = angular.module('TestApp', ['ngMaterial']);

TestApp.controller('MainController', function MainController($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, DialogController) {
    ...
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```

But I always get this:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DialogControllerProvider <- DialogController <- MainController

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject controllers. So remove `DialogController` from dependency injection parameters in `MainController` and use `controller: 'DialogController'` for dialog:

```
TestApp.controller('MainController', function MainController($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia) {

  // ...

  $scope.showImprintDialog = function(ev) {
    var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs')) && $scope.customFullscreen;
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'DialogController',
        templateUrl: 'impressum.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        fullscreen: useFullScreen
      })
      .then(function(answer) {
        $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
      }, function() {
        $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
      });
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $mdMedia('xs') || $mdMedia('sm');
    }, function(wantsFullScreen) {
      $scope.customFullscreen = (wantsFullScreen === true);
    });
  };

  // ...

});
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/46YtlQbndPQ4n27uGFGQ?p=preview

Comment: But have another problem, would like to put the controllers in an external file.

Comment: But I got another issue, would like to outsource the controllers ... but it cannot find them anymore... https://plnkr.co/edit/wPIsxH

Comment: sorry, bat description "but it cannot find them anymore". I got an error message "angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DialogController' is not a function, got undefined"

Comment: Did it like in your example, but it failed, .. now I got it. Copy and Paste fail, I surroundet my Controller Code wit function / use strict notation.